# What's the purpose of the "status_{hash}" files in the D:\home\data\jobs\continuous\{webjobname}" of Azure WebJobs?

Tags: azure-webjobs, kudu

We have one Continuous WebJob deployed on 9 instances running under an App Service Environment. If we browse to "*D:\home\data\jobs\continuous{webjobname}*" on the Kudu Site, we can see 9 files with the name "*status_{hash}*". The hash value in this name represents the first 6 characters of the instance names that we can see in the resource explorer for that WebApp.

Interestingly, some of these files contain:

```
{"Status":"Running"}
```

while others contain

```
{"Status":"Stopped"}
```

I might assume that this means that the WebJob is running on some instances (e.g. on 5 instances) and stopped in others (e.g. on 4). But is this expected at all? (our WebApp is **AlwaysOn** and the WebJob is **NOT** set to be singleton)

However, when reviewing "*job_log.txt*", we can see current activity related to that instance. And the "*status_{hash}*" file ModifiedOn is earlier than the activity log on the "job_log.txt" file.

```
[11/30/2016 03:39:20 > {hash}: INFO] Executed: 'Functions.{name}' (Succeeded)
```

Does anyone know the purpose of these files and how we should interpret them?

**[UPDATE]**

An extract from "job_log.txt":

```
[11/29/2016 19:28:59 > d6e0f6: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopped
[11/29/2016 19:29:28 > d6e0f6: INFO] Found the following functions:
[11/29/2016 19:29:28 > d6e0f6: INFO] Func1
[11/29/2016 19:29:28 > d6e0f6: INFO] Func2
[11/29/2016 19:29:28 > d6e0f6: INFO] Func3
[11/29/2016 19:29:51 > d6e0f6: INFO] Job host started
[11/29/2016 23:11:47 > d6e0f6: INFO] Executing: 'Functions.{name}' - Reason: 'New ServiceBus message detected on 'Tiers/Subscriptions/{name}'.'
```

The WebApp is at AEDT TimeZone, so,

```
11/29/2016 19:28:59 UTC = 11/30/2016 06:28:59 AEDT
11/29/2016 23:11:47 UTC = 11/30/2016 10:11:47 AEDT
```

And here the details of the corresponding *status_{hash}* file

```
File            Modified
status_d6e0f6   11/30/2016, 6:29:00 AM
```

Content:

```
{"Status":"Stopped"}
```

So we can see how the *status_{hash}* file was updated when the WebJob was stopped, but then it was not updated when the WebJob restarted.

Comment: Those files keep track of the status of the WebJob in each instance, as you guessed. But it's not normal for some to be stopped. On an instance where it's stopped, can you check whether the WebJob process is indeed not running?

Comment: Thanks for your response David. As mentioned in my original question, the _"job_log.txt"_ file contains activity for those WebJob instances. And the timestamps for those activity records are later than the ModifiedOn of the corresponding "status_{hash}" file. Is there any other way I should follow to check activity for those instances?

Comment: Use process explorer to see if it's running

Comment: Thanks David, We've been trying to use the Portal Process Explorer, but it hasn't been working properly for quite some time (couple of days). We get this error: _"Couldn't load process list, click refresh to try again."_ My understanding is that the Kudu Process Explorer and the Kudu api _/diagnostics/processes_ only monitor one instance. The server farm/service plan (9 x P3) seems to be OK, both below 40% CPU and Memory utilisation for the last 48 hours. Is there any other way to monitor if thoses instances are running?

Comment: If you go to Kudu UI, you just hit one instance at a time (there is an advanced way to pick which one). But from Portal, you should see all of them at once. It's puzzling that it's not working.

Comment: See [this post](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/03/access-specific-instance/) for info on selecting the Kudu instance you hit.

Comment: This is the response the portal is getting when we open the Process Explorer 
`{"Message":"Unable to connect to the remote server","HttpStatusCode":"InternalServerError","XMsServerRequestId":null,"StackTrace":null}`

Comment: I'll have a look at the post to select the instance on Kudu, Many thanks for your prompt responses David!

Comment: I managed to select the instance from the Kudu Site and the WebJob is effectively running. However, the "status_{hash}" file is still showing "stopped". So in summary, the WebJob instance is running, but the corresponding file status is not being updated accordingly. Thanks for all your help David, and please let me know if you wanted me to provide more information in case you wanted to reproduce this behaviour? Regards,

Comment: Good that the WebJobs are in fact running, but this is puzzling. If you do a full site restart, does it all get fixed up, or do some of the instances still have that condition?

Comment: We cannot recycle the WebApp at the moment. This is happening on a production environment and on the same WebApp, there are some APIs which we must not impact. Restarting the WebApp fixed the issue last time, but after a while, some of the files were showing "stopped". The number of files showing stopped has been changing, e.g. sometimes only 1, other times 6 (out of 9).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else has the same question or face similar issues:

The *“status_{hash}”* files in the D:\home\data\jobs\continuous{webjobname}" are meant to contain the status of the continuous WebJob on that particular instance. However, apparently, in some scenarios you should not expect this status to be always accurate.

If you want to check the status of a continuous WebJob running on multiple instances, the best way to do it would be to use the Azure Portal Process Explorer and check if the WebJob process under that instance is running.

If you are unlucky enough (as me) and your Portal Process Explorer is not responding, you can use the Kudu Process Explorer and check that particular instance by connecting to that paricular one.

[This post](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/03/access-specific-instance/) summarises how to get the instance Ids and how to connect to the corresponding Kudu site instance. However, there are newer simpler ways to do it.

To get the instance Ids, you can get them from the Resource Explorer, e.g.

https://resources.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{rg_name}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{app_service_name}/instances

And then, you would need to edit the corresponding ARRAffinity cookie on your browser before browsing Kudu and getting to its Process Explorer. You can validate that you are connecting to the correct instance by checking the Environment Variable "WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID" shown in the Kudu site.

HTH